# Cake bake error with easyphp

Tags: cakephp

I've some troubles when I try to use the cake console. I'm on windows seven. When trying to do a cake bake model, I get the following error:

```
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
        #0 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(98): DboSource->__construct(Array)
        #1 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(837): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
        #2 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(782): ModelTask->getAllTables(NULL)
        #3 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(863): ModelTask->listAll(NULL)
        #4 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(186): ModelTask->getName()
        #5 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(84): ModelTask->_interactive()
        #6 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Command/BakeShell.php(102): ModelTask->execute()
        #7 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(375): BakeShell->main()
        #8 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(177): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
        #9 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69):   ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
        #10 /opt/lampp/cake/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php(24): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
        #11 {main}
```

Does anybody can solve this issue ?
Tkx !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not define your database settings.
Define your database connection at `app/config/Database.php`.

It looks roughly like the following.
(Remember to update at least the `login`, `password` and `database` for your setup)

```
<?php
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '',
    'login' => 'YOUR MYSQL USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR MYSQL PASSWORD',
    'database' => 'YOUR DATABASE NAME',
    'schema' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => ''
);
```

Refer to this [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#cake-database-configuration) if you need some guidance.

Comment: Whene I do just the database config into the cli that's ok but on i try the make a cake bake model I've the screen error above ! So just the database config works !